Standard deviation in 3d space
Is there anything analogous to the standard deviation, but in three-dimensional space?
I have two set of data



SET A






3D coordinates






point
X
Y
Z




a1
2.09
-1.2
4.03


b1
7.31
8.5
-2.8


c1
-3.45
1.12
9.4



and



SET B






3D coordinates






point
X
Y
Z




a2
3.04
5.2
-4.15


b2
-1.11
-8.78
-0.15


c2
7.73
-5.16
-3.56



Which points are less spread in space and more close together ?  Τhose of set A (a1,b1,c1) or those of set B (a2,b2,c2)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why can't you just use the usual formula for standard deviation, but using distances? (Geometrically, the mean is the centroid, and so on). I'm assuming you're just showing some example points here - if you do only have 3 points in each set, you might want to think of a more meaningful measure, depending what the dataset actually is.

@i don't know what i am doing $\qquad$
$\bar D$ of set A = 7.43 and $\bar D$ of setB = 7.09.$\qquad$ Points of set B are closer together ie less spread in 3d space. $\qquad$Is $\bar D$ the same with $\sigma$, were $\sigma$ = $\sqrt {\sigma^2}$ and $\sigma^2$ = ${\frac {\sum_{i=1}^n ((x-x_i)^2+(y-y_i)^2+(z-z_i)^2)}n}$ $\qquad$were (x,y,z) = $\frac 1n$ $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ $\qquad$ is the centroid ? $\qquad$I am asking because i saw this in another post, but i was not sure how to use it. Your approach is simplest and allowed me to apply my data to it.
